# Where did my gold go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can only carry small amounts of gold at a time but if I go to the 'General' area I have a lot of gold listed there. Is that normal? How can I get my gold when I need it?

Answer (score 6):

This is normal. What you're looking at is your [Statistics page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Statistics#General). There are two entries there about gold, one for **Gold Found** and one for **Most Gold Carried**. These are all-time records that you've set, and include gold that you've spent and no longer have. It's just a bragging-rights number.

The gold in your inventory is all the gold you have.